# How to map a range of values to a single value in FME

Tags: fme-form, fields-attributes

A dataset with a set of points has an attribute called HEIGHTS which is filled with numbers like, 10.8, 0.4 and 150.6 etc... I want to transform this dataset to a shapefile. In the transformation I want to add a new column to the shapefile which will need to contain a color code.

How can I map the height values to this color code?

For example all heights between 5-10 should have the color dark blue,  all heights between 10 and 20 should have the color light blue etc......
I tried to use the valuemapper transformer, but it only seems to work for 1:1 mappings.

I am using FME 2009.  This means that I cannot use the AttributeRangeMapper and AttributerRangeFilter transformers. Can I conclude that what I want is not possible in FME 2009 and I should look at a newer version on FME?

Comment: How about using the AttributeRangeFilter?  Give each range it's own Output Port. Then use the StringFormatter to replace the numeric values with your color values.

Comment: Does 2009 have PythonCallers? If so, you could just write a function that runs the value through a set if if statements and set the color code that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FME 2009 supports Tester transformers; you could chain a bunch of those together (one for each  range) and tag features that pass accordingly while passing fails onto the next tester for further evalutation.

Comment: I have tested it and it works. It's not pretty en can make your workspace really large if you have a large number of classes to go through, but it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

not ideal but as a bit of a fudge you could use an attribute range mapper on the height column - each output then going to a separate attribute creator for the colour column

Comment: I am affraid both the attributeRangeFilter and AttributeRangeMapper only exist in FME 2010 and onward and not in FME 2009. Such a shame, because the do seem to give me what I want.